# Linux Debian - unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, debian

How can I remove unmet dependencies on my Linux Debian?

Result of **apt-get -f install** is following:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Correcting dependencies... failed.
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libc-bin: Breaks: libc6 (< 2.10) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
>
> libc-dev-bin: Depends: libc6 (> 2.13) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
>
> ```
>             Recommends: manpages-dev but it is not installed
> ```
>
> libssh2-1: Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.2) but 1.4.1-1 is installed
>
> libssh2-1-dev: Depends: libssh2-1 (= 0.18-1) but 1.2.6-1 is
>   installed
>
> locales: Depends: glibc-2.13-1
>
> nscd: Depends: libc6 (> 2.13) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
>
> E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be
>   caused by  held packages.
>
> E: Unable to correct dependencies

**uname -r** result:

> 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5.028stab095.1

I also tried to **apt-get remove libssh2-1**, **apt-get remove libc-dev-bin** etc. but it doesn't work for me. It's annoying and I cannot install any other packages.

Any suggestions how can I fix that?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  Can you remove 2.7-18lenny7?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try follow this step 1 by 1

apt-get autoclean

apt-get -f install

dpkg --configure -a

apt-get -f install

apt-get -u dist-upgrade

or try "aptitude" instead of "apt-get"

Comment: does not work  when you have problem in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: This is good but I also had to fix my /etc/apt/sources.list and in this file I put what they show as an example here: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: Good tip about using `aptitude`, it unblocked me, thanks!